# Trying to catch keyboard focus but

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

Is there any possibility to see to what object of project keyboard focus belongs to? Cant't catch it.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FocusManager.GetFocusedElement` to return to the naturally selected control.

```
 Control focusedControl = (Control)FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
```

Use `Keyboard.FocusedElement` to control the keyboard selection.

```
 Control focusedControl = (Control)Keyboard.FocusedElement;
```

Both return an `IInputElement` can be converted to `control`.